# How can I get the project name for a timelog issue entry using the project ID from a Gitlab GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, gitlab

I'm using the [graphql explorer](https://gitlab.com/-/graphql-explorer) for gitlab and I'm trying to get timelog entries for a given user (as below).

The response gives me a `projectId` which I assume I'd have to use in a subsequent query (I don't believe I can get it in the same query?), but the `project` object doesn't let me find the project by ID, only fullpath.

Am I correct in understanding that I would need to use the `projects` query and provide the id there?  In trying that (query below), I just get the error `12345678 is not a valid GitLab ID.` (obviously I'm using a real ID given previously).

So, two points/questions I guess:

- The timelog entry provides a projectId which I can't use in either the project or projects query to get the project name?
- I can't just return the project name directly in the same query as the original user timelog one?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

```
{
  users(usernames: ["user1"]) {
    nodes {
      id
      username
      timelogs(startDate: "2022-05-03T09:00:00") {
        nodes {
          issue {
            projectId
          }
          timeSpent
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  projects(ids:[12345678]) {
    nodes {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So the `ids` required for `projects` need to be prefixed with `gid://gitlab/Project/` which will get me an array of nodes matching the project ID! 

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I use:

```
{
  group(fullPath: "groupname") {
    name
    timelogs(startTime: "2022-04-01", endTime: "2022-04-30", username: "roberto") {
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
      nodes {
        
        user {
          username
        }
        issue {
          iid
          webUrl
          state
          projectId
          title
        }
        spentAt
        timeSpent
        summary
        note {
          body
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).